# зафиксировать выпадающее меню

Tags: javascript, css

Я не очень силен в javascript, подскажите как зафиксировать выпадающее меню, чтобы оно было всегда активно?  Сайт http://1285021.sn312395.web.hosting-test.net/
Меню справа в шапке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элемент, в котором лежит меню:

```
<div class="toggle_cont">
</div>
```

Нужно добавить ему атрибут  style="display: block;"

```
<div class="toggle_cont" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

Это именно то, что сейчас делает скрипт, только с анимацией.

Comment: зачем inline стили?

Comment: Так на практике работает какойто код с анимацией. Можно сделать и не инлайновые, но тогда нужно отлкючить код с анимацией, так как он при закрытии меню добавляет инлайновые display: none;, что будет иметь большую специфичность.

Comment: специфичность в чем?)

Comment: специфичность - это приоритет применения css правил. то есть инлайновые стили всегда переопределят внешние при конфликте.